# wp_set_object_terms NOT working on CPT, but wp_set_post_terms does

Tags: posts, terms

I have a function that runs with user input variable (comma separated numeric string) to update the terms (by id) in a custom taxonomy on a custom post type. Even though [the docs say](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms) I should use `wp_set_object_terms`, I can only get my terms to update by using `wp_set_post_terms`. The following code will work (using `wp_set_post_terms` but not using `wp_set_object_terms` at the end):

```
if(isset($request['custom_tax'])) {
$customtaxarray = explode(",",$request['custom_tax']);
$only_integers = true;
foreach ($customtaxarray as $testcase) {
    if (!ctype_digit($testcase)) {
    $only_integers = false;
    }
    }
if ($only_integers) {
$customtax = $customtaxarray;
} else {

return array(
                'code' => 'missing_integers',
                'data' => array(
                    'status' => 403,
                    'message' => "custom_tax must be one or more (comma separated) integers.",
                ),
            );
}
//update custom_tax
wp_set_post_terms($request['cpt_post_id'], $customtax, 'custom_tax' );

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much trial and error, I have found a solution that will allow wp_set_object_terms to be used. Despite already checking if my strings were integers, apparently I needed to convert the array explicitly as well. So I changed this:

`$customtax = $customtaxarray;`

to this:

`$customtax = array_map('intval',$customtaxarray);`

and suddenly `wp_set_object_terms` now works. That does not explain why `wp_set_post_terms` was working instead (unless perhaps it does this conversion automatically?), but at least this is now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to observe the data types!
This is a working code:

```
wp_set_object_terms((int)$id, array_map('intval',$relation), 'product_cat');
```